# Search and replace with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

Last week I accidently externalized all my strings of my eclipse project. I need to revert this and my only hope is sed. I tried to create scripts but failed pathetically because I'm new with sed and this would be a very complicated operation. What I need to do is this:

Strings in `class.java` file is currently in the following format(method) `Messages.getString(<key>)`. Example :

```
    if (new File(DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH).exists()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            if (!new File(DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH
                    + Messages.getString("VSDataSource.89") + i).exists()) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                getnewvfspath = DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH
                        + Messages.getString("VSDataSource.90") + i; //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The key and matching Strings are in `messages.properties` file in the following format.

```
VSDataSource.92=No of rows in db = 
VSDataSource.93=Verifying db entry : 
VSDataSource.94=DB is open
VSDataSource.95=DB is closed
VSDataSource.96=Invalid db entry for 
VSDataSource.97=\ removed.
key=string
```

So I need the java file back in this format:

```
    if (new File(DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH).exists()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            if (!new File(DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH
                    + "String 2" + i).exists()) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                getnewvfspath = DataSource.DEFAULT_VS_PATH
                        + "String 1" + i; //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I accomplish this with `sed`? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" is to make a sed script out of the message.properties:

```
$ sed 's!/!\\!;s!\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)!s/"\1"/"\2"/g!' message.properties > message.sed
$ sed -f messages.sed class.java > class.java.reverted
$ rm messages.sed
```

You start with something like:

```
VSDataSource.92=No of rows in db = 
VSDataSource.93=Verifying db entry : 
VSDataSource.NN=Foo/bar
```

And end up with:

```
s/"VSDataSource.92"/"No of rows in db= "/g
s/"VSDataSource.93"/"Verifying db entry : "/g
s/"VSDataSource.NN"/"Foo\/bar"/g
```

Answer (score 1):

No source control? ***tsk***, ***tsk***.  I'd suggest fixing *that* problem before running this script that worked for me on a very small sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for i in `seq 92 97`
do
    X=$(sed -n s/^VSDataSource.$i=//p messages.properties)
    sed -i "s+Messages.getString(\"VSDataSource.`echo $i`\")+\"`echo $X`\"+g" class.java
done
```

Of course, change the args to seq and sed (*java instead of class.java, perhaps).  Seriously, though, there's no way this is the best solution to your problem.  If it has an 'externalize strings' button, shouldn’t your IDE have an 'internalize strings' button?